# asp.net website doesn't run on server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, runtime-error

I'm getting a runtime error when I try to access my asp.net website on a server. It works fine from my computer when I test it but once I upload it to my host, the runtime error appears.

I get this message:

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

My webhost is godaddy. The server is indeed windows and according to their tech support they have all the frameworks installed and up to date (I'd imagine this anyway from such a large host).

Basically they say it's an error on my end but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I made the website with Visual Studio 2010. I'm new to this technology.

Comment: Did you set the `customErrors` attribute in the Web.config as the error states?

Comment: On the error you're getting there should be a framework version at the bottom of the page, can you post the framework version you're targeting as well as the framework version on the error?

Comment: Yes. I also made sure the programming language on the server is set to framwork 4.0.

Comment: fixed it. adjusted programming language and it seemed to fix the problem. customer support never mentioned this. :/

Comment: set <customErrors mode="Off"/> value to On, so that you can see the error